# modify & design croped image

Tags: html, css, image, crop

I cropped an image in html & css . When i am coding a `<span>` tag the cropped image displayed. But I need to know how can I modify it.

I have the following code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
.design  {
padding-left:25px;
background:url('Flings.png') no-repeat top left;
display: inline-block;
height: 17px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 550px;
}
</style>
<div style="height: 200px;">
<span class="design" style='font-size: 40px;'></span>
</div>
```

When I am using the span tag, the cropped image displayed. But I want to modify it.

Example:

```
<span class="desgin" style='color: red;'></span></h3>
```

I want to color the image itself and change it's size and I am little stuck here.

Hope you understood me well, I will be glad for any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to scale and then colorise the image? You can scale the image using `background-size` but this isn't very well supported. [CSS3 filters unfortunately don't have a colorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/) filter also.

You should do this using an `<img>` so scaling works without `background-size` and then use another transparent element on top of the image to provide the tint effect. Unfortunately `<img>` tags don't support pseudo-elements so need to use a wrapper.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/hk43H/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="red-tint">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
    /* scale the image */
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
}

.red-tint {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
}

.red-tint:after {
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    display:block;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

### Update

Ah you want to crop, then that's just a matter of using background-position. You will need to give negative left and top positions to `background-position` which represent the offsets from the top-left corner of the image. For example, this will draw a 200x100 chunk of the image which is 100px in from the left side of the image and 20 px down from the top.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/zQ8Y5/)

```
.design {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:url(https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png) no-repeat;
    background-position:-100px -20px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately it wasn't helpful, I need to crop an image (not scale it), and than color it and making the cropped image much bigger